# Teradata 15: Error 3806: Table/view/trigger name is ambiguous

Tags: sql, teradata

I've created an `VOLATILE MUTISET TABLE` with name `tmp`, and then trying to create another table as merging `tmp` and permanent table. 
It results in `Error 3806: Table/view/trigger name 'tmp' is ambiguous`

What am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE tmp2 AS
(
SEL
   a.*,
   tmp.id
from library.table a
inner join tmp 
on a.sk = tmp.sk
)
WITH DATA
PRIMARY INDEX (id)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
```

Comment: how come extra comma after on condition? are you sure tmp is successfully created?

Comment: yeah, it is created. (removed comma - sry)

Comment: can you add alias for tmp as well? for example, tmp t and replace tmp with t in join and select?

Comment: There might be a table named `tmp` in your default database, you can qualify the Volatile Table using your user name: `myusername.tmp`

Comment: so can we create gtt/vt with name already existing in default db? wouldn't it throw an error?

Comment: When you create the table and there's no existing table with that name it will be successful. But it's a bit more complicated, when you qualify a tablename that database is added to the list of default databases.  In your example there might be a table named `library.tmp`

Comment: let's name it tmp3

Answer (score 1):

The following entry in Teradata [manual](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/rgAb27O_xRmMVc_aQq2VGw/~ckVXnGYLBLVcUVqRz7pVQ) says the following:

**Resolving Table References**

When encountering an unqualified table name, the system looks for a table by that name in all of the following databases.

1. The default database
2. Any databases referenced by the SQL request
3. The logon user database for a volatile table by that name

The search must find the table name in only 1 of those databases. Teradata Database returns the “ambiguous table name” error message if the table name exists in more than 1 of those databases.